# One or more UTF8 fields contain non-UTF 8 data, editing might give unexpected results

Tags: oracle, utf-8, oracle-apex

I have text file(iso-8859-1) located on Oracle Linux 7.2, which i'm trying to load in table on my Oracle DB 12.1c(AL32UTF8).

```
     declare
     f       Utl_File.File_Type;
     v_Buffer  varchar2(1000);
     v_Table   Parse.Varchar2_Table;
     v_Nfields integer;
 begin
     f     := Utl_File.Fopen('SA', '1.txt', 'R');
     if Utl_File.Is_Open(f) then
         loop
             begin
                 Utl_File.Get_Line(f, v_Line, 1000);
                 if v_Line is null then
                     exit;
                 end if;
                     Parse.Delimstring_To_Table(v_Line, v_Table, v_Nfields, Chr(9));
                     --insert into ...
                 end if;
             exception
                 when No_Data_Found then
                     exit;
             end;
         end loop;
     end if;
     Utl_File.Fclose(f);
 end;
```

With using [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20693822/Is-there-a-way-to-parse-a-tab-delimited-text-file-using-UTL-FILE.html) to parse

I have beautiful(correct) output in pl/sql developer with message "One or more UTF8 fields contain non-UTF 8 data, editing might give unexpected results"

[image: correct image]

and uncorrect output in Apex 5.

[image: apex image]

Can I do something with this? I'm trieng convert? translate in oracle and more...

**UPDATE 1**

```
select *
  from nls_database_parameters
 where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET%';

PARAMETER               VALUE
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET        AL32UTF8
```

Comment: ISO-8859-1 does not handle Cyrillic characters. Shown result cannot be from a ISO-8859-1 file.

Comment: There is no Oracle character set called `Al16UTF8`. What exactly is your `NLS_CHARACTERSET`, resp. `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, you are correct, my fault. I'll update my question.

Comment: Maybe another solution is to convert your file to UTF-8 before you load it (for example with command line tool [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html), should be installed along Oracle server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UTL_FILE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70899) says

> UTL_FILE expects that files opened by UTL_FILE.FOPEN in text mode are encoded in the database character set.

Obviously this is not the case.

Use [DBMS_LOB.OPEN()](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66736) to open a BFILE (see [BFILENAME](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions020.htm#SQLRF00610)) as `RAW` value and convert it with [UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR()](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_i18n.htm#ARPLS71156) function to VARCHAR2.

Then you can use your `Parse.Delimstring_To_Table` function to parse lines.

Consider to use [EXTERNAL TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm#g1017623) or [SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm#g1013706), perhaps they are easier to use.

Comment: I can't understand how i can read blob line by line. If I use `UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(dbms_lob.substr(bfile,1000,n))`, I read a length. How I can read whole line, but not length?

Comment: You have to split the CHAR manually at `CHR(13)`, the you get the lines.

Comment: My way was, BFILE with UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR to CLOB. Then CLOB split Chr(13) by rows, then row split Chr(10) by columns.